# Wifi problem on the first start droid turbo

Tags: motorola-droid

I reseted to factory defaults and in first boot in initialization step it requires wifi connection to setup but not detecting wifi network, how to get through this help please

Comment: Put an activated SIM in the device, if there is a valid mobile data connection you should have the ability to Skip this step. Some newer devices cannot be activated without a data connection of some kind so they can check FRP.

Comment: BTW, this is a Verizon specific device I believe, often newer models cannot be activated without a connection to Verizon's network, you may need a working Verizon SIM.